# Unable to launch the App using appium on IOS

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, debugging, appium

I'm trying to run automation script on my app using appium on mac, but the below error keeps showing up:
**Error launching instruments: Instruments crashed on startup**
However, the same code and capabilities works fine on other device.
Please note that the device is connected with XCode and with ios_webkit_debug_proxy command.

**My log file:**

```
EtQs-MacBook-Pro:~ etqmobiledev4$ appium
[Appium] Welcome to Appium v1.6.4
[Appium] Appium REST http interface listener started on 0.0.0.0:4723
[HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session {"desiredCapabilities":{"platformVersion":"9.3.4","bundleId":"com.etq.reliance.mobile","takesScreenshot":"true","autoWebview":true,"platformName":"iOS","udid":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxx","deviceName":"test Device","nativeWebTap":true}}
[debug] [MJSONWP] Calling AppiumDriver.createSession() with args: [{"platformVersion":"9.3.4","bundleId":"com.etq.reliance.mobile","takesScreenshot":"true","autoWebview":true,"platformName":"iOS","udid":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxx","deviceName":"test Device","nativeWebTap":true},null,null,null,null]
[debug] [BaseDriver] Event 'newSessionRequested' logged at 1492412294768 (09:58:14 GMT+0300 (EEST))
[Appium] Creating new IosDriver (v1.18.2) session
[Appium] Capabilities:
[Appium]   platformVersion: '9.3.4'
[Appium]   bundleId: 'com.etq.reliance.mobile'
[Appium]   takesScreenshot: 'true'
[Appium]   autoWebview: true
[Appium]   platformName: 'iOS'
[Appium]   udid: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
[Appium]   deviceName: 'test Device'
[Appium]   nativeWebTap: true
[debug] [iOS] IosDriver version: 1.18.2
[BaseDriver] The following capabilities were provided, but are not recognized by appium: takesScreenshot.
[BaseDriver] Session created with session id: 11438b7e-19c7-4751-82c1-6898373da26e
[debug] [iOS] Xcode version set to 7.3.1
[debug] [iOS] Not auto-detecting udid.
[debug] [iOS] Removing any remaining instruments sockets
[debug] [iOS] Cleaned up instruments socket /var/folders/cm/qjdc9my10tqch37161y2trrw0000gn/T/instruments_sock
[debug] [iOS] Localizable.strings is not currently supported when using real devices.
[debug] [iOS] Creating instruments
[debug] [UIAuto] Preparing bootstrap code
[debug] [UIAuto] Dynamic bootstrap dir: /Users/etqmobiledev4/Library/Application Support/appium/bootstrap
[debug] [UIAuto] Dynamic env: {"nodePath":"/usr/local/Cellar/node/7.3.0/bin/node","commandProxyClientPath":"/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-uiauto/build/lib/bin/command-proxy-client.js","instrumentsSock":"/var/folders/cm/qjdc9my10tqch37161y2trrw0000gn/T/instruments_sock","interKeyDelay":null,"justLoopInfinitely":false,"autoAcceptAlerts":false,"autoDismissAlerts":false,"sendKeyStrategy":"grouped"}
[debug] [UIAuto] Dynamic bootstrap code: // This file is automatically generated...o not manually modify!
[debug] [UIAuto] Dynamic bootstrap path: /Users/etqmobiledev4/Library/Application Support/appium/bootstrap/bootstrap-5bb0f5d1b8cc2392.js
[debug] [UIAuto] Reusing dynamic bootstrap: /Users/etqmobiledev4/Library/Application Support/appium/bootstrap/bootstrap-5bb0f5d1b8cc2392.js
[debug] [iOS] Creating iDevice object with udid xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
[debug] [iOS] Running ios real device reset flow
[debug] [iOSLog] Attempting iOS device log capture via libimobiledevice idevicesyslog
[debug] [iOSLog] Found idevicesyslog: '/usr/local/bin/idevicesyslog'
[debug] [iOS] App is installed.
[debug] [iOS] fullReset not requested. No need to install.
[debug] [iOS] Starting UIAutoClient, and launching Instruments.
[debug] [UIAuto] Instruments socket server started at /var/folders/cm/qjdc9my10tqch37161y2trrw0000gn/T/instruments_sock
[debug] [Instruments] Instruments is at: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/instruments
[debug] [Instruments] Attempting to launch instruments, this is try #1
[Instruments] Launching instruments
[debug] [Instruments] Attempting to run app on real device with UDID 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
[debug] [Instruments] Found Insruments-Without-Delay: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-instruments/thirdparty/iwd7
[debug] [Instruments] Spawning instruments with command: '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/instruments -t /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/PlugIns/AutomationInstrument.xrplugin/Contents/Resources/Automation.tracetemplate -D /var/folders/cm/qjdc9my10tqch37161y2trrw0000gn/T/appium-instruments/instrumentscli0.trace -w xxxxxxxxxxxxxx com.etq.reliance.mobile -e UIASCRIPT "/Users/etqmobiledev4/Library/Application Support/appium/bootstrap/bootstrap-5bb0f5d1b8cc2392.js" -e UIARESULTSPATH /var/folders/cm/qjdc9my10tqch37161y2trrw0000gn/T/appium-instruments'
[debug] [Instruments] And extra without-delay env: {}
[debug] [Instruments] And launch timeouts (in ms): {"global":90000}
[debug] [Instruments] [INST STDERR] 2017-04-17 09:58:20.195 instruments[31339:2552745] WebKit Threading Violation - initial use of WebKit from a secondary thread.
[debug] [Instruments] [INST STDERR] Instruments Trace Error : Target failed to run: Permission to debug com.etq.reliance.mobile was denied. The app must be signed with a development identity (e.g. iOS Developer).
[debug] [Instruments] Instruments exited with code: 253
[Instruments] Error launching instruments: Instruments crashed on startup
[debug] [Instruments] Attempting to launch instruments, this is try #2
[Instruments] Launching instruments
[debug] [Instruments] Attempting to run app on real device with UDID 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
[debug] [Instruments] Found Insruments-Without-Delay: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-instruments/thirdparty/iwd7
[debug] [Instruments] Spawning instruments with command: '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/instruments -t /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/PlugIns/AutomationInstrument.xrplugin/Contents/Resources/Automation.tracetemplate -D /var/folders/cm/qjdc9my10tqch37161y2trrw0000gn/T/appium-instruments/instrumentscli0.trace -w xxxxxxxxxxxxxx com.etq.reliance.mobile -e UIASCRIPT "/Users/etqmobiledev4/Library/Application Support/appium/bootstrap/bootstrap-5bb0f5d1b8cc2392.js" -e UIARESULTSPATH /var/folders/cm/qjdc9my10tqch37161y2trrw0000gn/T/appium-instruments'
[debug] [Instruments] And extra without-delay env: {}
[debug] [Instruments] And launch timeouts (in ms): {"global":90000}
[debug] [Instruments] [INST STDERR] 2017-04-17 09:58:30.323 instruments[31343:2552962] WebKit Threading Violation - initial use of WebKit from a secondary thread.
[debug] [Instruments] [INST STDERR] Instruments Trace Error : Target failed to run: Permission to debug com.etq.reliance.mobile was denied. The app must be signed with a development identity (e.g. iOS Developer).
[debug] [Instruments] Instruments exited with code: 253
[Instruments] Error launching instruments: Instruments crashed on startup
[debug] [Instruments] Attempting to launch instruments, this is try #3
[Instruments] Launching instruments
[debug] [Instruments] Attempting to run app on real device with UDID 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
[debug] [Instruments] Found Insruments-Without-Delay: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-instruments/thirdparty/iwd7
[debug] [Instruments] Spawning instruments with command: '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/instruments -t /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/PlugIns/AutomationInstrument.xrplugin/Contents/Resources/Automation.tracetemplate -D /var/folders/cm/qjdc9my10tqch37161y2trrw0000gn/T/appium-instruments/instrumentscli0.trace -w xxxxxxxxxxxxxx com.etq.reliance.mobile -e UIASCRIPT "/Users/etqmobiledev4/Library/Application Support/appium/bootstrap/bootstrap-5bb0f5d1b8cc2392.js" -e UIARESULTSPATH /var/folders/cm/qjdc9my10tqch37161y2trrw0000gn/T/appium-instruments'
[debug] [Instruments] And extra without-delay env: {}
[debug] [Instruments] And launch timeouts (in ms): {"global":90000}
[debug] [Instruments] [INST STDERR] 2017-04-17 09:58:39.873 instruments[31347:2553085] WebKit Threading Violation - initial use of WebKit from a secondary thread.
[debug] [Instruments] [INST STDERR] Instruments Trace Error : Target failed to run: Permission to debug com.etq.reliance.mobile was denied. The app must be signed with a development identity (e.g. iOS Developer).
[debug] [Instruments] Instruments exited with code: 253
[Instruments] Error launching instruments: Instruments crashed on startup
[debug] [Instruments] Attempting to launch instruments, this is try #4
[Instruments] Launching instruments
[debug] [Instruments] Attempting to run app on real device with UDID 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
[debug] [Instruments] Found Insruments-Without-Delay: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-instruments/thirdparty/iwd7
[debug] [Instruments] Spawning instruments with command: '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/instruments -t /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/PlugIns/AutomationInstrument.xrplugin/Contents/Resources/Automation.tracetemplate -D /var/folders/cm/qjdc9my10tqch37161y2trrw0000gn/T/appium-instruments/instrumentscli0.trace -w xxxxxxxxxxxxxx com.etq.reliance.mobile -e UIASCRIPT "/Users/etqmobiledev4/Library/Application Support/appium/bootstrap/bootstrap-5bb0f5d1b8cc2392.js" -e UIARESULTSPATH /var/folders/cm/qjdc9my10tqch37161y2trrw0000gn/T/appium-instruments'
[debug] [Instruments] And extra without-delay env: {}
[debug] [Instruments] And launch timeouts (in ms): {"global":90000}
[debug] [Instruments] [INST STDERR] 2017-04-17 09:58:49.506 instruments[31351:2553246] WebKit Threading Violation - initial use of WebKit from a secondary thread.
[debug] [Instruments] [INST STDERR] Instruments Trace Error : Target failed to run: Permission to debug com.etq.reliance.mobile was denied. The app must be signed with a development identity (e.g. iOS Developer).
[debug] [Instruments] Instruments exited with code: 253
[Instruments] Error launching instruments: Instruments crashed on startup
[debug] [Instruments] Attempting to launch instruments, this is try #5
[Instruments] Launching instruments
[debug] [Instruments] Attempting to run app on real device with UDID 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
[debug] [Instruments] Found Insruments-Without-Delay: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-instruments/thirdparty/iwd7
[debug] [Instruments] Spawning instruments with command: '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/instruments -t /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/PlugIns/AutomationInstrument.xrplugin/Contents/Resources/Automation.tracetemplate -D /var/folders/cm/qjdc9my10tqch37161y2trrw0000gn/T/appium-instruments/instrumentscli0.trace -w xxxxxxxxxxxxxx com.etq.reliance.mobile -e UIASCRIPT "/Users/etqmobiledev4/Library/Application Support/appium/bootstrap/bootstrap-5bb0f5d1b8cc2392.js" -e UIARESULTSPATH /var/folders/cm/qjdc9my10tqch37161y2trrw0000gn/T/appium-instruments'
[debug] [Instruments] And extra without-delay env: {}
[debug] [Instruments] And launch timeouts (in ms): {"global":90000}
[debug] [Instruments] [INST STDERR] 2017-04-17 09:58:58.964 instruments[31355:2553417] WebKit Threading Violation - initial use of WebKit from a secondary thread.
[debug] [Instruments] [INST STDERR] Instruments Trace Error : Target failed to run: Permission to debug com.etq.reliance.mobile was denied. The app must be signed with a development identity (e.g. iOS Developer).
[debug] [Instruments] Instruments exited with code: 253
[Instruments] Error launching instruments: Instruments crashed on startup
[Instruments] Error: We exceeded the number of retries allowed for instruments to successfully start; failing launch
    at Object.wrappedLogger.errorAndThrow (../../lib/logging.js:63:13)
    at Instruments.launch$ (../../lib/instruments.js:223:15)
    at tryCatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:67:40)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke [as _invoke] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:315:22)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.prototype.(anonymous function) [as throw] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:100:21)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:136:37)
 Error: We exceeded the number of retries allowed for instruments to successfully start; failing launch
    at Object.wrappedLogger.errorAndThrow (../../lib/logging.js:63:13)
    at Instruments.launch$ (../../lib/instruments.js:223:15)
    at tryCatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:67:40)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke [as _invoke] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:315:22)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.prototype.(anonymous function) [as throw] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:100:21)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:136:37)
[MJSONWP] Encountered internal error running command: Error: We exceeded the number of retries allowed for instruments to successfully start; failing launch
    at Object.wrappedLogger.errorAndThrow (../../lib/logging.js:63:13)
    at Instruments.launch$ (../../lib/instruments.js:223:15)
    at tryCatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:67:40)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke [as _invoke] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:315:22)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.prototype.(anonymous function) [as throw] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:100:21)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:136:37)
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 46715 ms - 232
```

Comment: This is the key: `Target failed to run: Permission to debug com.etq.reliance.mobile was denied. The app must be signed with a development identity (e.g. iOS Developer).`. Are you signing your application?